# Why angular subscribes multiple times?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this structure:

- product.service(for service)
- product-search component(for setting the current checked object)
- compare-product component(for subscribing the current checked object)

I want to subscribe to an object in the service whenever the compare-product is loaded. It seems fine at first. But, when I hit the back button to the product-search, then load the compare-product again, it subscribes twice. When I go back and load again, it is called three times. Back, load again, called four times, and so on.

these are the codes:

service:

```
//product.service
.......
private checkedSrc = new BehaviorSubject([]);
currentChecked = this.checkedSrc.asObservable();

.......
setChecked(checked: string[]){
    this.checkedSrc.next(checked);
}

resetChecked(){
    this.checkedSrc.next([]);
}
.......
```

product-search component:

```
......
compare(){
    this.products_valid = true;
    this.productSvc.setChecked(this.checked);
    this.router.navigate(['compare']);
}
......
```

compare-product component:

```
...
products: string[];
isLoading: boolean = true;

constructor(
  private productSvc: ProductsService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.productSvc.currentChecked.subscribe(p => {this.products = p; console.log(this.products)})
}
```

I have tried it without navigating to the compare component. When I first call the compare function it subscribes once, call the compare again it subscribes twice, call again it subscribes three times, and so on.

```
......
compare(){
    this.products_valid = true;
    this.productSvc.setChecked(this.checked);
    this.productSvc.currentChecked.subscribe(p =>{console.log(p);})
}
......
```

Button that calls it:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 20px;" (click)="compare()">Compare</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have tried to reset the object with resetChecked() everytime the compare method called, but still the same...

Comment: You're subscribing to it every time the component is initialized. Why *shouldn't* it subscribe multiple times? You should unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to unsubscribe to the observable when the component is destroyed. Each time you load the component, you have 1 subscription.

Comment: Perfect solution!!

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you call `subscribe` the source - `checkSrc` in this case - gets informed that a new subscriber wants to get data. The source doesn't know when you leave the page, it still keeps track of one subscriber. When you return `subscribe` is called again and now the source has two subscribers.

You have several options to solve the problem. The first one is to unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy` method:

```
subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.productSvc.currentChecked.subscribe(p => {this.products = p; })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

A better option is to use the `async` pipe.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.products = this.productSvc.currentChecked();
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products | async">{{product.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see `this.products` no longer refers to the products but the stream of products. In order to use in in your template you add the `async` pipe. On of the advantages is that you don't need to subscribe and unsubscribe yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 6, if you're using the ngOnDestroy approach remember to use a reference to the subscription.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription //import from rxjs 

  constructor(private myService: MyService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.myService.myMethod.subscribe(...);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

If, in ngOnDestroy, you call unsubscribe directly on this.myService.myMethod you'll end up getting a "ObjectUnsubscribedError" exception.